Basic doubt in quantum mechanics
Do entities like electrons, which are considered point particles in Classical Mechanics, actually have a definite position at a particular time (irrespective of it can be measured or not)?

Depends on the interpretation of QM. My gut feeling says that the very most of physicist would answer "no", though.

The overwhelming majority opinion on this is "no." If the electron is described by a wavefunction, it is spatially diffuse throughout space.

You mean it's mass and charge is also distributed ?

An electron is a point particle. The wavefunction does not tell us where the electron is. It only tells us the probability that, if we measure, we find the electron at position $\vec r$. The probability density is $|\psi(\vec  r)|^2$. The very fact that  the wavefunction has a single point as an argument is already an implicit agreement to treat the electron as a point particle.

This does not mean the electron has a "definite location." It only can be said to have a definite location once we measure its location, at which time the wavefunction reduces to $|\vec r\rangle$, the eigenfunction of the position operator with the correct eigenvalue.

@MattHanson The electron is definitely not "spatially diffuse." The wave function describes our knowledge of the system; it only gives us the probability density that we find the electron at $\vec r$ when we measure. The diffuseness of the wave function does not mean that the electron is diffuse in any way. For example, the square of the wave function could be mapped out via experiment, but it would require many experiments on many identically prepared systems. The result of any given measurement will be a specific position (within the uncertainty of the detector).

@hft That is, to a large extend, an interpretation. The ontological status of the wave function is not settled.

@hft you seem to suggest that the electron has a definite position even though it cannot be predicted. This interpretation is wrong if you believe in locality, as shown by the observation of the violation of the Bell's inequalities.

I don't care about the ontological status of the wave function. I know how it is used and how it has been used for nearly 100 years.

@Frotaur No, I do not suggest that. Did you read my answer? Did you read where I wrote: "Note: this discussion should not be taken to imply that the electron has a definite position. Nor should the discussion below."

@ hft We get a particular position value only when we measure it . Then how can we say so surely that it has no particular position when we don't measure it. It may have it maynot have but we cannot know which is true .

This is a question that haunts anyone who is interested about the foundations of quantum mechanics.
In standard textbook quantum mechanics, the answer would be no, the electron does not have a definite position at any particular time. The best description you have of the state of the electron is given by its wavefunction, which tells you the probabilities of finding an electron at any particular position. Only when you measure the position, the electron will, momentarily, have a definite position. This is known as collapsing the wavefunction.
However, there are interpretations of quantum mechanics that do associate a position with the electron at all points in time. For example:

In the Bohm$-$de Broglie interpretation (also known as Pilot Wave Theory), the electron does have a definite position in space. The probability densities predicted by quantum mechanics are interpreted as epistemic probabilities, which means that it all comes down to one's lack of knowledge of the system. The electron then moves according to the guiding equation under the influence of a physical wavefunction.

In the many-worlds interpretation, superpositions are identified with splitting worlds. In each world, a particle would take one possible path given by quantum mechanics. In this sense, particles would have definite positions, contextual to each world.


At the end of the day, the answer to your question comes down to your preferred interpretation of quantum mechanics. The ones that I've mentioned still have many kinks and are not completely consistent. Many physicists choose not to think too much and simply go with textbook quantum mechanics or more phenomenological interpretations like Copenhagen or operationalism, as the interpretation does not influence experimental results.
Honestly, the real answer is: for now, nobody knows for sure.

In substance the answer is no. If you take electrons and pass them through an interference experiment, then the result in general can't be explained by assuming it just went down one of the paths in the interference experiment. Rather, at the end of the experiment you will see a pattern of light and dark stripes and the pattern changes depending on how many slits you have open, so some places have no electrons that formerly would have electrons. So something is going through all the slits and that thing will act just like an electron if you expose it to a magnetic field or whatever. At the same time you will only ever see it at one detector at a time. The wavefunction acts like there are multiple versions of the electron going down all of the possible paths interfering with one another, but you can only detect one of them directly. See "The Fabric of Reality" by David Deutsch Chapter 2 for a detailed explanation of a single particle interference experiment.
You also can't explain electron's interactions with atoms, energy shells and so on by saying the electron is at a single position since interference effects are part of the explanation for atomic orbitals.
Real measurements are just interactions that copy some information from the measured system to a measuring device and in general to the environment around the measuring device as well and the states that are detected are narrowly peaked on the scales of position and momentum of everyday life but they aren't at a single point:
https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0306072
The idea of point particles in quantum theory is only ever a crude approximation.

It is entirely possible that the electron takes a single path but it is influenced, from a distance, by the the other slit, due to the electromagnetic interactions with the particles inside the barrier. There is nothing about this experiment that contradicts the classical view of the electron.

@Andrei No. You only get interference if the electron beam overlaps with both slits which can be tested if electrons can be detected at either slit. This can't be explained by the electron being influenced by interactions of the electron going through one slit with material at the other slit since such an interaction would happen whether or not there was a non-zero probability for the electron to go through the other slit. Such interactions will take place but they don't explain single electron interference.

The electron always interacts with the electrons and nuclei the barrier consists of, it's a fundamental property of any charged particle. This does not mean that the pattern will always be the same, it depends on the initial state. Two massive objects always interact gravitationally, but sometime you can get a circular orbit, some other time an elliptical one, or you could get no orbit at all if the initial velocity is too high. So, there is no wonder that the two-slit pattern depends on where you direct the beam relatively to the barrier.


Are entities like electrons which are considered point particles in classical Mechanics have actually have a definite position at a particular time (irrespective of it can be measured or not)?

The electron is (or "is modelled exceptionally well as") a point particle in quantum mechanics. This means that the electron can be described by the Hamiltonian of a point particle where the position (a single position, since it is a point particle) is promoted to a position operator, a la:
$$
H = \frac{\hat {\vec p}^2}{2m_e} + V(\hat {\vec r})\;,
$$
where $\hat{\vec r}$ is the position operator and $\hat{\vec p}$ is the momentum operator.
The above Hamiltonian does not describe electron spin, but we will not worry about that for now. The above Hamiltonian does not describe any internal structure of an electron, thus an electron is well-modeled as a point particle.
Note: This discussion should not be taken to imply that the electron has a definite position. Nor should the discussion below.

When you go about solving the Hamiltonian for a given potential, say the Coulomb potential, you end up with solutions that are called "wave functions." Those wave function solutions do not mean that the electron is not a point particle. To the contrary, the position operator still has eigenvalues that are real triples of numbers, i.e., the eigenvalues of  the position operator are consistent with a point particle.
What the wavefunction $\psi(\vec r)$ tells you is only the probablity density that you measure the electron at a location $\vec r_0$. That probability density is:
$$
|\psi(\vec r_0)|^2\;,
$$
which, again, I will point out that the probabilty density is associated with a specific point in space, here denoted by $\vec r_0$, meaning that the electron is being treated as a point particle.
The fact that the wavefunction "spreads out" over space does not mean that the actual electron is "spread out." The wavefunction only tells us the probability for measuring the electron at a given point, which, again, means that the electron is a point particle, since we (in principle) measure its position at a single point.
In practice, we can not measure position with absolute certainty, not only due to the uncertainty principle, but also due to the finite precision of any real experiment. However, we can measure the position of an electron with an apparatus, and within the uncertainty of the apparatus we will always measure it at one point, never multiple different points at one. So, again, an electron is well modeled as a point particle.

As a further appeal to authority, open up the Particle Data Booklet and you will see that there is no evidence of any internal structure for an electron. Further supporting the statement that an electron is a point particle.

Nothing in the above discussion should be interpretted to imply that the electron always has a definite position. The position is only determined when a measurement of the position is made. If the position is measured as $\vec r$, the wavefunction reduces to:
$$
|\vec r\rangle\;,
$$
which is an eigenstate of the position operator.
Of course, in practice, there is no measuring device with infinite precision. So, in practice, the electron will be measure to be within $\Delta r$ of $\vec r$ and the wave function will reduce to:
$$
\frac{\int_{\Delta r} d^3r \psi(\vec r)|\vec r\rangle}{|\int_{\Delta r} d^3r \psi(\vec r)|\vec r\rangle|^2}
$$
